# Firebase cloud messaging with Angular 12 and Firebase v9

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am using angular 12 and firebase v9. I have been trying to implement FCM with Angular and django. I have facing an issue maybe you have too. We can use this post to discuss and come to a solution.

Before you tell me that there are many posts about it, let me tell you I have tried everything that is on the internet. Tutorials are old, methods are depreciated. So we have to start new.

For the start, I have created a service worker called firebase-messaging-sw.js.
here is the code.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";


const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
apiKey: "***",
authDomain: "***",
databaseURL: "***",
projectId: "***",
storageBucket: "***",
messagingSenderId: "***",
appId: "***",
measurementId: "***"
});
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
```

Then manifest.json

```
{
"gcm_sender_id": "***"  
}
```

Added both of them in angular.json under assets and manifest.json in index.html, I put the code like:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Then i call the gettoken script in component code is

```
const messaging = getMessaging();
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '***' 
}).then((currentToken) => {
              if (currentToken) {
                
                console.log('hey')
              } else {
                
                console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to 
generate one.');
               
              }
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
             
            });
```

Now after serving the app from HTTP or either ng serve -ssl

we are getting the above error.
Let's discuss this.

Update: I have added angular/pwa which created it's own service worker and manifest file. Should I add my firebase code it that??

Also on building the angular/pwa app, getting the error
service worker generation failed.

let's take time and solve this issue together.

Comment: Hi @abhey. I'm facing kinda same issue. First of all I was wondering why you didn't use @angular/fire which simplifies the work. With that library I've partially solved the problem: I suggest you to try this guide: https://medium.com/mighty-ghost-hack/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-cc80d9b36f82

Comment: Hi @abhey, I strongly believe you could help me. How did you solve (if so) the
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'
 in the 'firebase-m..-sw.js' service worker? I've been struggling with this whole day.
I understand, that this needs to be bundled with a bundler (like webpack) to use imports, but how to get this work for Angular? I've done pretty much you've done, and still can't figure out how to build the web successfully. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Ben, there is no need to add the js file in components, you can just add ServiceWorkerModule.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy:'registerImmediately'
    }),   in module .ts and add js in file in angular.json

Comment: May I know if we can use @angular/fire in angular13 ... I am not getting token on request permission

Comment: Yes you can. It is updated. try to recreate the error by some way and see if you are doing something wrong. I would suggest something. Never use the latest version maybe go for 12.5,6 but not latest. There is  not too much support available for it also sometimes it is unstable.